# Why can I not use a DefaultClient to access Calendar API?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I'd like to use [Google's quickstart code to access my Google Calendar](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/go). It works when I follow the steps, but [changing it to use a DefaultClient](https://github.com/smaslennikov/cal-calc/commit/0b1a1ad0e8a53a64be43012c4fb13449fe9bbd88) results in a 403 error:

```
$ go run quickstart.go
2021/02/09 14:03:19 Unable to retrieve next ten of the user's events: googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication
scopes.
More details:
Reason: insufficientPermissions, Message: Insufficient Permission
exit status 1
```

This is my current code to retrieve local Default Credentials and use them for generating an httpClient:

```golang
client, err := google.DefaultClient(oauth2.NoContext, calendar.CalendarReadonlyScope)
if err != nil {
   log.Fatalf("auth broke: %v", err)
}

srv, err := calendar.New(client)
if err != nil {
   log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve Calendar client: %v", err)
}

t := time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)
events, err := srv.Events.List("primary").ShowDeleted(false).
   SingleEvents(true).TimeMin(t).MaxResults(10).OrderBy("startTime").Do()
if err != nil {
   log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve next ten of the user's events: %v", err)
}

fmt.Println("Upcoming events:")
if len(events.Items) == 0 {
   fmt.Println("No upcoming events found.")
} else {
   for _, item := range events.Items {
      date := item.Start.DateTime
      if date == "" {
         date = item.Start.Date
      }
      fmt.Printf("%v (%v)\n", item.Summary, date)
   }
}
```

The code does work if I create an OAuth2 credential in my GCP Project and use that, but that's not the approach I'd like to use here.

1. I understand I may need to use a 3-legged approach to get an OAuth2 token, but I can't find any examples on how to do this with Default Credentials.
2. Can I not use an approach similar to [`gcloud` CLI's built-in token generation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token)?

Comment: Hi ! What are you exactly trying to achieve ? In order to use Google Calendar API you will need to use [oAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2). From what you have described I believe that your intention is to access to Google calendar not with the credentials of any specific user but rather with the credentials of your application. Is my guess correct? If you, would a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) suit you case scenario ?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf The quickstart documentation requires creating an OAuth2 client JSON and using that. I'd like to instead use my existing authentication generated by the `gcloud` CLI on my local workstation. This is generally referred to as [Default Credentials](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2/google#FindDefaultCredentials). I know I can get an OAuth2 token using `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` but I can't seem to replicate this functionality in my code.

Comment: Hi ! Have you read the [oAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth#OAuth2Authorizing) authorization flow? I think the G Could token is differnt from the access token. With the g cloud cli token do you refer to [this one](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token)?